# ng2-charts thousands separator on data label

Tags: angular, charts, label

In this Example
    http://embed.plnkr.co/7fGsiuRjcF0M0Ffeoml2/

```
If I Change data to: 
    data: [2000, 3000, 4000, 8000, 12000, 12850]

Is it possible put thousand sepator on dataset label ? 
Like this : 
5,000
10,000
15,000
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it !
I need use callback function on xAxes property. Like this:

```
barChartOptions = {
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        fontSize: 13,
        fontStyle: 'normal',
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
          callback: (dataLabel, index)=> {                  
            let decimalPipe = new DecimalPipe('pt-BR');
            return decimalPipe.transform(dataLabel, '1.0-0');
          }
      }
    }]
  },
  ...
```

Thanks !